# How to work with float left right and vertical align middle?

Tags: html, css

I need to align `logo` to left and `navigation` to right and the text in `logo` and `navigation` must be aligned bottom of the `logo-nav` div.

**Note:** Without flex box

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.navigation {
  float: right;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-nav">
  <div class="logo">Partners</div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
      <li class="nav-li">OUR SPIRIT</li>
      <li class="nav-li">OUR OFFER</li>
      <li class="nav-li">OUR VISIONARY</li>
      <li class="nav-li">CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post your css also

Comment: I added css. please check it out

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom` or `flexbox` properties.

Comment: I am unable to do it. New to css. Please help me

Comment: Why no flexbox?

Comment: May I suggest a couple improvements? Use a `clearfix` instead of a clearing DIV and use `text-transform: uppercase;` to make text uppercase instead of doing it in the markup.

Comment: @torazaburo beacaue of this `In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property.`

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I don't see you using `min-height` with flex items in your CSS.

Comment: @hungerstar there is no support in IE9<= to flex box I think

Comment: What versions of IE do you need to support?

Comment: Oh @Mr_Perfect, you need to be more explicit. Someone asked, _"why not flexbox?"_ and you replied because of min-height, not lack of support in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Flexbox` for this. You just need to set `margin-left: auto` on `navigation` and `align-items: flex-end` for vertical-align.

```css
.logo img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.logo-nav, .nav-ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.navigation {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-nav">
  <div class="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"></div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
      <li class="nav-li">OUR SPIRIT</li>
      <li class="nav-li">OUR OFFER</li>
      <li class="nav-li">OUR VISIONARY</li>
      <li class="nav-li">CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use CSS tables.

```css
.logo img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.logo-nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.logo,
.navigation {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.navigation {
  text-align: right;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50">
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
      <li class="nav-li">OUR SPIRIT</li>
      <li class="nav-li">OUR OFFER</li>
      <li class="nav-li">OUR VISIONARY</li>
      <li class="nav-li">CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can we achieve it without using flex.

Comment: I said without flex box

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo-nav{
  height:40px;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navigation{
  float:right;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
.navigation ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
.navigation ul li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  margin:0 5px;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  height:100%;
}
.logo{
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
}
```

```html
    <div class="logo-nav">
        <div class="logo">+CoPartners</div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="nav-ul">
                <li class="nav-li">OUR SPIRIT</li>
                <li class="nav-li">OUR OFFER</li>
                <li class="nav-li">OUR VISIONARY</li>
                <li class="nav-li">CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I said without flex box

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css

```
.nav-ul li{float:left; list-style:none;padding:0 5px;}
.nav-ul{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: what need to be done on logo. how u need to align it?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not possible with floats, you can use `display: inline-block` instead. It works like a poor man's `flex`.

```
.logo-nav {
  text-align: justify;
}
.logo-nav::after {
  /* you can omit this by using `text-align-last` */
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}
.clear {
  /* this element is obsolete now */
}
```

Note: there must be no space between `.logo`and `.navigation` in your markup.

Comment: I modified my answer to add your alignment

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use position absolute?

```css
li{
   float: left;
   padding: 0 5px;
}
ul{     
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
img{
  display: block;
}
.logo{
  float: left;
}
.logo-nav{
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}
.logo-nav:after{
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-nav">
        <div class="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"></div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="nav-ul">
                <li class="nav-li">OUR SPIRIT</li>
                <li class="nav-li">OUR OFFER</li>
                <li class="nav-li">OUR VISIONARY</li>
                <li class="nav-li">CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```